# How to select value from a dropdown using JScript (not JavaScript) with TestComplete

Tags: jscript

Currently I'm working on TestComplete automation tool. I'm facing a problem in selecting a value from a dropdown using Jscript. It can done easily in javascript by

```
document.getElementById("id").options[1].selected=true
```

I cant do it using JScript'. I've tried

```
Browsers.Item(btIExplorer).Run("Page URL"); //opening the browser and running a URL
    browser=Aliases.browser; //creating alias of browser object
    page=browser.Page("PageURL"); //creating a page object for the page opened
   page.NativeWebObject.Find("id", "defaultLocationBinder_newOrExisting", "input") // This is the dropdown
```

I'm not able to find any suitable option to select the options in the dropdown which are given in the `<option></option>` tags

Answer (score 3):

I just wrote this piece of code and was able to do it.
Use the selectedIndex to set the option you want.

use the object spy to check the properties/methods you can use with the object.

```
function loginDropDown()
    {
      var dropDown = Sys.Browser("iexplore").Page("*").FindChild("Name","Select(\"myList\")",10,true)
      dropDown.selectedIndex = 1

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The NativeWebObject.Find method returns a native object while you may want to work with a TestComplete wrapper. Use the Find or FindChild method to get such a wrapper and the Clickitem method to select a specific item.

```
function test()
{
  var b = Sys.Browser("iexplore");
  b.ToUrl("http://support.smartbear.com/message/?prod=TestComplete");
  var page = b.Page("http://support.smartbear.com/message/?prod=TestComplete");
  var cBox = page.FindChild("ObjectIdentifier", "ddlRequestType", 20);
  cBox.ClickItem("General product question");
}
```